# Com definir a data limite no datepicker do bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-3, datepicker

Quando eu uso o `Jquery Ui DatePicker`, consigo definir uma data máxima utilizando o atributo `maxDate`.

Assim:

```
$('#data-solicitacao').datepicker({maxDate: 'now'})
```

Achei que no DatePicker do Bootstrap 3 fosse a mesma coisa, porém não é.

Como é então que posso definir uma data máxima no DatePicker do Bootstrap?

Comment: Essa pergunta ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117284/como-setar-maxdate-no-datepicker-para-sete-dias-depois-da-data-selecionada/117308#117308

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, amiguinho. Obrigado

Comment: @DiegoF tem muito código aí, hein. Se olhar meu exemplo (de como faço no Datepicker do Jquery UI), vai ver que é bem simples. Queria algo assim no Bootstrap também

Answer (score 4):

Tens de dar o valor ao `endDate`.

```
var today = new Date();
$('#data-solicitacao').datepicker({
   endDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    endDate : new Date('2016-05-20'),
});
```

Aqui tem um [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/2pmn1ems/6/)